# python-social-auth: get user with GitHub username

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to find a specific user by github username.

```
for i in UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(provider='github').all():
    print(i)
```

I want to find the user with a specific GitHub user name (not site username), say, "DanielPBak". How would I do this?

UserSocialAuth can only filter by provider and user, so it doesn't seem possible to use only filter(). However, iterating through the filtered users seems impossible, because it doesn't seem possible to access the UserAuth username, only the site's username.

How can I get the UserSocialAuth username?

dir(i) doesn't reveal anything to do with an auth username or github username.